# C++ client to WCF server failes with error "A message containing a fault was received from the remote endpoint"

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, visual-c++

I have WCF web service builded on C# with simple function `void Test1();` 
I have C++ client programm that calls this function. C++ function that calls web service:

```
bool Test1(  )
{


    if (initProxy())
    {
        int fncReslt =0;
        int idr =0;
        HRESULT hr = ERROR_SUCCESS;

        hr = BasicHttpBinding_ISupportServiceW_Test1(proxy, 
            heap,
            NULL,
            0,
            NULL,
            error);
        return isErr(hr,fncReslt);
    } else return false;
}
```

Function BasicHttpBinding_ISupportServiceW_Test1 returns error

`hr = 0x803d0013 A message containing a fault was received from the remote endpoint.`

What is the road map of fixing such errors?

Dump from `wstrace.bat` is below. I braked `wstrace.bat` with CTRL+C after I hot error. Maybe that is why it has no correct end.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Web Services API Trace Viewer Tool version 1.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2009.
All rights reserved.

TimeStamp,ProcessID,ThreadID,Event,Operation,Error,Info
130722078095318038,11724,27160,"enter","WsCreateError"
130722078095318086,11724,27160,"exit","WsCreateError"
130722078095318102,11724,27160,"enter","WsCreateHeap"
130722078095318407,11724,27160,"exit","WsCreateHeap"
130722078095318433,11724,27160,"enter","WsCreateServiceProxyFromTemplate"
130722078095808630,11724,27160,"exit","WsCreateServiceProxyFromTemplate"
130722078095808733,11724,27160,"enter","WsOpenServiceProxy"
130722078096137656,11724,27160,"exit","WsOpenServiceProxy"
130722078253270902,11724,27160,"enter","WsCall"
130722078253272271,11724,27160,"(unknown)",""
130722078253318836,11724,27160,"(unknown)",""
130722078253320793,11724,27160,"sending message start ","message# (1)"
130722078253321219,11724,27160,"io started","Send"
130722078255817101,11724,21688,"io completed","Send",0x0,0
130722078255817136,11724,21688,"io started","Receive"
130722078255817290,11724,21688,"io completed","Receive",0x0,0
130722078255817550,11724,21688,"sending message       ","message# (1)",
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <Test1 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
130722078255817566,11724,21688,"sending message stop  ","message# (1)"
130722078255817707,11724,21688,"(unknown)",""
130722078255817755,11724,21688,"io started","Receive"
130722078255817855,11724,21688,"io completed","Receive",0x0,256
130722078255817900,11724,21688,"io started","Receive"
130722078255817938,11724,21688,"io completed","Receive",0x0,256
130722078255817967,11724,21688,"io started","Receive"
130722078255818009,11724,21688,"io completed","Receive",0x0,218
130722078255818015,11724,21688,"io started","Receive"
130722078255818057,11724,21688,"io completed","Receive",0x0,0
130722078255818192,11724,21688,"received message start","message# (2)"
130722078255819693,11724,21688,"received message      ","message# (2)",
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the &lt;serviceDebug&gt; configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
130722078255819702,11724,21688,"received message stop ","message# (2)"
130722078255819965,11724,21688,"error","",0x0,The fault reason was: 'The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception inform
130722078255820171,11724,21688,"error","",0x803d0013,A message containing a fault was received from the remote endpoint.
130722078255820337,11724,21688,"error","",0x0,The body of the received message contained a fault.
130722078255820472,11724,27160,"exit failed","WsCall",0x803d0013
130722081052431928,752,20488,"enter","WsCreateError"
130722081052431947,752,20488,"exit","WsCreateError"
130722081052431969,752,20488,"enter","WsCreateHeap"
130722081052431972,752,20488,"exit","WsCreateHeap"
130722081075017010,752,20488,"enter","WsFreeHeap"
130722081075017020,752,20488,"exit","WsFreeHeap"
130722081075017030,752,20488,"enter","WsFreeError"
130722081075017036,752,20488,"exit","WsFreeError"
130722081075034231,752,20488,"enter","WsCreateError"
130722081075034250,752,20488,"exit","WsCreateError"
130722081075034257,752,20488,"enter","WsCreateHeap"
130722081075034260,752,20488,"exit","WsCreateHeap"
130722081075036829,752,20488,"enter","WsFileTimeToDateTime"
130722081075036848,752,20488,"exit","WsFileTimeToDateTime"
130722081075039273,752,20488,"enter","WsResetHeap"
130722081075039276,752,20488,"exit","WsResetHeap"
130722081075039478,752,20488,"enter","WsCreateServiceProxy"
130722081075044411,752,20488,"exit","WsCreateServiceProxy"
130722081075055377,752,20488,"enter","WsOpenServiceProxy"
130722081075055477,752,20488,"exit","WsOpenServiceProxy"
130722081075058129,752,20488,"enter","WsCall"
130722081075059191,752,20488,"(unknown)",""
130722081075062225,752,20488,"enter","WsAddMappedHeader"
130722081075062366,752,20488,"exit","WsAddMappedHeader"
130722081075062376,752,20488,"enter","WsRemoveMappedHeader"
130722081075062398,752,20488,"exit","WsRemoveMappedHeader"
130722081075062402,752,20488,"enter","WsAddMappedHeader"
130722081075062411,752,20488,"exit","WsAddMappedHeader"
130722081075209836,752,20488,"(unknown)",""
130722081075276961,752,20488,"sending message start ","message# (1)"
130722081075280111,752,20488,"io started","Send"
130722081084471049,752,13540,"io completed","Send",0x0,0
130722081084474862,752,13540,"io started","Receive"
130722081084474962,752,13540,"io completed","Receive",0x0,0
130722081084475308,752,13540,"sending message       ","message# (1)",
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetUpdateDownloadInformation xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/SoftwareDistribution/Server/UpdateRegulationWebService">
      <cookie>
        <Expiration>2015-04-03T20:13:45Z</Expiration>
        <EncryptedData>s6p2/0NFfvJJz/37Up2/FNGgpOqrMuVrcBGnJYTJasjfua9fxEaFMod+hpCwrUlsTpnyNQsMUM48fhBYn9QWTZZumS7JhDXyMQCtZHv0VfVFAE6qJR0x7bAm8clNgA67poOJ+UrFPqk3rPXu6Gj5q0AFf8zHqvuw30V6nxI2o6jiSuu4DaGyD+v8TW6WrNpGZRdDUG+FghTzavprqzdR3Lmz0csJzL1gPr7VfyJT9P7XTHBg/BsRtBbK35+Qsy7gKdrfO1tMLmolF8lplEiggg==</EncryptedData>
      </cookie>
      <updateIds>
        <UpdateIdentifier>
          <Id>90bbcb43-314e-41f3-b64b-fd20b095c643</Id>
        </UpdateIdentifier>
        <UpdateIdentifier>
          <Id>e0d60382-b31a-4745-932a-028a630c6902</Id>
        </UpdateIdentifier>
      </updateIds>
    </GetUpdateDownloadInformation>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
130722081084475318,752,13540,"sending message stop  ","message# (1)"
130722081084475549,752,13540,"(unknown)",""
130722081084475607,752,13540,"io started","Receive"
130722081084475652,752,13540,"io completed","Receive",0x0,256
130722081084475668,752,13540,"io started","Receive"
130722081084475684,752,13540,"io completed","Receive",0x0,256
130722081084475693,752,13540,"io started","Receive"
130722081084475709,752,13540,"io completed","Receive",0x0,84
130722081084475712,752,13540,"io started","Receive"
130722081084475732,752,13540,"io completed","Receive",0x0,0
130722081084475866,752,13540,"received message start","message# (2)"
130722081084477156,752,13540,"received message      ","message# (2)",
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetUpdateDownloadInformationResponse xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/SoftwareDistribution/Server/UpdateRegulationWebService">
      <GetUpdateDownloadInformationResult>
        <RegulatedUpdates>
          <RegulatedUpdateInformation>
            <UpdateId>90bbcb43-314e-41f3-b64b-fd20b095c643</UpdateId>
            <Properties>
              <ConfigurationProperty>
                <Name>AR</Name>
                <Value>0</Value>
              </ConfigurationProperty>
              <ConfigurationProperty>
                <Name>BucketPrefix</Name>
                <Value>PL</Value>
              </ConfigurationProperty>
            </Properties>
          </RegulatedUpdateInformation>
          <RegulatedUpdateInformation>
            <UpdateId>e0d60382-b31a-4745-932a-028a630c6902</UpdateId>
            <Properties>
              <ConfigurationProperty>
                <Name>AR</Name>
                <Value>0</Value>
```

Comment: If you look at the reply message in the stack trace, you'll see "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the &lt;serviceDebug&gt; configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."

Comment: First two options are a) turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults on the service and b) enable WCF Tracing.  You can also check the event viewer on the server hosting the service to see if any .NET exceptions were captured there.